clang-format does not split long if statements
In my clang-format configuration file, I have set a ColumnLimit of 180 along with other relevant settings, as shown in the snippet below. However, I’ve noticed that clang-format sometimes allows if statements with multiple conditions to exceed this limit (even going up to 279 characters in some cases).
Here is my configuration:
---
Language: Cpp
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
AlignOperands: Align
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: false
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: false
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile: false
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakAfterAttributes: Never
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
ColumnLimit: 180
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DisableFormat: false
IndentWidth: 2
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000
RemoveSemicolon: false
Standard: Latest
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never


I am not using clang-format directly but through MegaLinter (version 7.10.0), which uses clang-format version 17.0.6: https://megalinter.io/7.10.0/descriptors/c_clang_format/
Below is a minimal reproducible example:
#include "bluetoothStatus.h"
int main()
{
  boolean bluetoothIsValid = FALSE;
  if ((bluetooth_IsInEnabledMode_b() == TRUE) && (bluetooth_IsCurrentlyAuthenticated_b() == TRUE) && (RetrieveStatusOfDevelopmentAdvertisement_u8() == FALSE) && (IsBluetoothChipPoweredOn_b() == TRUE))
  {
    bluetoothIsValid = TRUE;
  }

  return bluetoothIsValid;
}



Later update: I tested the above clang-format configuration with this example on the https://clang-format-configurator.site/ on clang-format version 17.0.6. With newer versions and the same config file the formatting works properly, so now I am almost certain this indicates a bug in the 17.0.x version of clang-format.

Show a [mre]. You likely get a syntax error in the condition, unbalanced parenthesis.

@3CxEZiVlQ the codebase in question is a production one, there is no syntax error. Build and other checks on the formatted code pass. I scanned the codebase and there are 23 if statements longer than the allowed 180 limit, I'll put an example below:
if ((bluetooth_IsInAdvertisingMode_b() == FALSE) && (bluetooth_IsCurrentlyConnected_b() == FALSE) && (RetrieveStatusOfProductionAdvertisement_u8() == FALSE) && (BluetoothAdvertisementDetails_s.DefaultAdvertisementSet_s.SetInitializationStatus_u8 == STATUS_OK))

Please [edit] the question and add the missing information to there.

Can't replicate. This works as expected. The ifs are split at the last && and || respectively. Please post a [mre] so we don't guess.

Unless you use the -i (in place) option to clang-format, it won't modify the original code -- it will put the reformatted code somewhere else, or will just print messages about things that are misformatted.  So you may be running clang-format, but then looking at the unformatted code.

@3CxEZiVlQ sorry for the missing information, I updated the question with a minimal reproducible example, and the tools and versions I'm using. I now suspect my problem is rather a bug in the 17.0.6 version of clang-format.

@ChrisDodd that is not the case, parts of the files containing if statements are modified when formatting the code, but the long if statements remain untouched, please see my newest update on the question.
